# docker: executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: python, docker

Using AWS instance based on ubuntu 18.04, Docker version 19.03.10, build 9424aeaee9.
I got the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

after trying to execute the code:

```
docker run --name test1 c73eada5a5fa
```

where "c73eada5a5fa" is my container id after being built using:

```
sudo docker build -t my_username/repository .
```

Here is my docker:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY . /PFE_exec
CMD ["make", "PFE_exec"]
CMD ["sudo","apt","install","unzip"]
CMD ["echo","requirements installed!"]
CMD ["unzip","home/ubuntu/PFE/aa.zip"]
CMD ["python","home/ubuntu/PFE/test.py"]
CMD ["python","home/ubuntu/PFE/test2.py"]
CMD ["python","home/ubuntu/PFE/test3.py"]
```

Using python3 instead of python doesn't resolve the problem as well.
I don't understand where is the problem.
Any help?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `python` or `python3` pre-installed in `ubuntu:18.04` image, if you want to use python in your Docker, you probably want to change your base image to [python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), e.g. `FROM python:3`.

Besides, in your Dockerfile, there should be [only one `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), what you need is [`RUN` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) instead of `CMD`.

Comment: I changed the code but now i'm getting this error.
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"sudo\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
and when i delete the sudo line code, just to test, i get this error:
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory